How to listen to Enhanced Measurement events from js?
I want to pass Enhanced Measurement events from Google Analytics through an iframe. Specifically I want to capture events, such as form_start and form_submit, etc and then send them to the parent window via window.parent.postMessage.
I tried to log all the events pushed via the window.dataLayer.push, but it appears to me that enhanced measurement events don't directly use it - I see the events firing in Tag Assistant but not in the console.
Is it possible for me to access those events through my JavaScript?
